# Cors issue withe vue , nest and docker under k8s

Tags: vue.js, nginx, cors, nestjs

I have cors problem "Quellübergreifende (Cross-Origin) Anfrage blockiert: Die Gleiche-Quelle-Regel verbietet das Lesen der externen Ressource auf https://users.example.com/login. (Grund: CORS-Kopfzeile 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' stimmt nicht mit 'http://app.igneos.cloud' überein)."

I try to login via vuejs (test.example.com) on a nestjs microservice (user.example.com). Vue and nestjs are deploy on k3s.

For this I use this docker file for vue

```
# build stage
FROM node:lts-alpine as build-stage
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# production stage
FROM nginx:stable-alpine as production-stage
COPY --from=build-stage /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

and this is my nestjs cors conf of (users.example.com)

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.enableCors({
    origin: 'test.example.com',
    methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS',
    credentials: true,
  });

  console.log('App started with port:', process.env.PORT);
  await app.listen(process.env.PORT);
}

bootstrap();
```

In vue set this in header of axios

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "*";
axios.defaults.headers.common["Access-Control-Allow-Methods"] =         "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS";

const user: { data: { token: string; isRegUserId: number } } =
          await axios.post(url, authDO);
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: `test.example.com` is not a valid Web origin, because it lacks a scheme and the `://` part. Besides, including headers `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in a request makes no sense since they are _response_ headers.